How to get resources from modules in android?
I have the main package "app" and module: "theme".
How can I get resources from the module (R.drawable....)?
settings.gradle have include ':theme'
and app build.gradle: implementation project(': theme')
The app can see functions from module, but can't find correct resources.
I have tried to import in class file the module, but it can't fiend path to module.

Add in build.gradle.kts like this
**kotlin
implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":theme")))

Declare in settings.gradle.kts
include(":theme")

Sync and Rebuild the project.
if already done so ignore it.
Now you want to use Resource path from "theme"
for example : your "theme" module package name like this com.theme.demo so your drawable image set like this
imageView.setImageResource(com.theme.demo.R.drawable.myImage)

that's it.

can it be if I have package name of module the same as the main app?

If both packages have the same name, there will be a problem. preferable to use separate package names for both of them.

for me com.mainproject.app.R.drawable.logo - logo from main project and  com.mainproject.app.R.drawable.logo_from_module - logo from module. What is wrong?

compiler confuse for which path use of drawable "theme" either "main_app" so compiler throw the error. so better is separate package name for both.

I will change namespace name in build.gradle of module package
